# MS Word, printed content is smaller since updating to Windows 10 (Larger borders)

Tags: microsoft-word, windows-10, printing, printer

I have regularly printed out the same MS Word documents for months and the printed area has consistently been the same over this time. Since updating to Windows 10 about 1 week ago, the printed area has changed. For some reason, when I print a document the content has been shrunk and the printed area on the page is much smaller compared to what was previously printed.

The printed document does not represent what is on the screen when editing the document, or what the print preview looks like.

For example, here is the gap between the borders of the page and the content before updating (I measured the gaps of the printed document with a ruler):

`Top - 9mm
Left - 12mm
Right - 19mm
Bottom - 9mm`

And after updating:

`Top - 9mm
Left - 20mm
Right - 16mm
Bottom - 26mm`

This is also really annoying as when I print labels, the printed area over laps the size of the stickers.

Also I have tried printing the document from my computer to a different printer and the margins are still different.

I am using MS Office 2013.

Hope you can help,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange but easy fix to this problem,

With the word document open, go to file-print. In the settings sections select the size of the paper you are using.

Even if your paper size is already pre-selected, just select it again.

Hit Print.

That's it.

[Here is a link to the answer source](http://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc9330cdw_us_eu_as&faqid=faq00002765_000)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your printer drivers don't work as expected. You haven't specified what printer you're using, so I can't point you to appropriate drivers, but you should be able to find them on printer manufacturer's website after selecting your printer model. Hopefully a new, fixed version has been released.

Comment: It' a brother MFC-9330 CDW. I'll check out the manufacturers site now and see if I can find drivers

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the latest drivers for the printer, and it is still printing with the large margins, do you have any ideas of what else might be the problem?